# How to remove all circles on map

Tags: android

I have added radius circles using the code below. But I'd like to remove all added circles. 
Also I want to limit drawing circles 3 or 4 circles .

```
@Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(point)   //set center
        .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
        .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        .strokeWidth(5);

        for(int i=0 ; 0 < 3 ; i++){
         myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
}
```

Comment: Just call remove() on all your Circle objects to erase them.

Comment: remove method using object remove in googlemap and Check this link helpful all method related Circle-http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html

Comment: can someone write a code how can I write it

Comment: You should probably tag the question with the google-maps-android-api-2 tag. That will improve the description of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick. Create an arraylist that keeps track of all the Circles you add to the map, and call DeleteCircles() when you want to delete the Circles from the map.

```
public class CustomMapFragment{

static List<Circle> mCircleList;

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

    if (mCircleList==null){
            mCircleList = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    }

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(point)   //set center
    .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
    .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
    .strokeWidth(5);

    if (mCircleList.size()<3){
    Circle mCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    mCircleList.add(mCircle)
    }
}

public void deleteCircles(){

    for (int i = 0 ; i <= mCircleList.size() -1; i++){
    Circle mCircle = mCircleList.get(i);
    mCircle.remove();
    }
    mCircleList.clear();
}
}
```